# Trouble Implementing SMS Sending App on Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to implement a very basic SMS sending App on Android.
The App simply involves the user to entering the desired phone number, and a message to be sent to that number. And upon pressing a button, the message is sent to the number.

However when I built and ran the app on a real device, and tap on the Send button, nothing happens. There must be a toast displaying a message, signifying the status of the message sent successfully or not.

Here is the code of my app so far:

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.abdulbasit.droidsms;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS =0 ;
Button sendBtn;
EditText txtphoneNo;
EditText txtMessage;
String phoneNo;
String message;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    txtphoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etphoneNo);
    txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMessage);

    sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendSMSMessage();
        }
    });
}

protected void sendSMSMessage() {
    phoneNo = txtphoneNo.getText().toString();
    message = txtMessage.getText().toString();

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "SMS sending failed! Please Try Again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
    android:text="DroidSMS" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="by Abdul Basit Mehtab" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etMessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="212dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter Message"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sendButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="117dp"
    android:text="Send" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etphoneNo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="159dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter Phone Number"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you do nothing if SMS permissions are already granted.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't handle the case that if you already have the SMS permission.Your logic flow should be like this.

Try To Send SMS -> Check Runtime Permission

Case 1 - If it granted Send SMS
Case 2 - If it is not granted ask permission ->  listen `onRequestPermissionsResult`
Case 3 - If it is denied(user marked don't ask again) -> send user to the App Settings

Also you need to be sure you added SMS permissions into your manifest.xml

```
protected void sendSMSMessage() {
   phoneNo = txtphoneNo.getText().toString();
   message = txtMessage.getText().toString();

   if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
        Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
        }
   } else {
        //this is the case you already have the permission
        sendTextMessage();
     }
}

protected void sendTextMessage(){
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: I have already added SMS permission into the AndroidManifest,xml file. Can you please modify my code to clarify the logic of handling cases?